# Invoking function on another thread in .Net Core

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, .net-core

I have a background thread with a long running task.

The background thread searches for files according to given filters.
The task might be running very long so I do not want to wait for task completion in order to show some results.

Additionally, I do not want to lock up my UI thread in order to check if there are new results from the background task.

I would rather want to notify my main thread: "Hey, there is a new search result added".
Kind of like windows explorer, showing search results while the search is still ongoing:
[image]

```
foreach (FileInfo itemToFilter in unfilteredSearchResults)
{
    if (extension == ".wav" || extension == ".flac" || extension == ".mp3")
    {
        // read audio information such as tags etc. Might take some time per file
        WaveFileLib.WaveFile.WAVEFile audioItem = new WaveFileLib.WaveFile.WAVEFile(audioFile.FullName);
        // Compare audio information such as tags, title, license, date, length etc to filter        
        if (Filter.AudioItemMatchesFilter(ref audioItem))
        {
            lock (threadLock)
            {
                // add search result to list of filtered audio files
                this.AudioItemList.Add(audioItem);
            }
            // notify main thread in order to refresh ui (if applicable)
            ParentView.AudioItemAdded();
        }
    }
}
```

the main thread can then generate a view from the newly added item.
Previously, this was quite easy with `BeginInvoke` but with .net core this possibility seems gone.

What are my alternatives / options to notify main thread about updated search results?

Comment: Use the [Progress](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) class. It was created for just this reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As supposed by Panagiotis Kanavos

```cs
public class AudioFileSearcher
{
    // task caller
    public AudioFileSearcher(string searchPath, bool includeSubFolders, Views.SoundListView.SoundList parentView)
    {
        this.progress1 = new Progress<int>(
        {
            backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged();
        });
        Task.Run(async () => await FindAudioFiles(progress1));
    }
    // reference to be updated by task and read by event Handler
    private Progress<int> progress1 { get; set; }
    // do something on task progress
    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged()
    {
        // Update UI on main thread or whatever
    }
    // Task
    public async Task FindAudioFiles(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        foreach(AudioItem itemToProcess in allFoundaudioItems)
        {
            // do long processing in background task
            // a new element has been generated, update UI
            if (progress != null) progress.Report(0); // ~fire event
        }
    }
}
```

works like a charm, items are beeing loaded
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<WaveFileLib.WaveFile.WAVEFile> query =
    from itemToFilter in unfilteredSearchResults.ToObservable()
    where extension == ".wav" || extension == ".flac" || extension == ".mp3"
    from audioItem in Observable.Start(() => new WaveFileLib.WaveFile.WAVEFile(audioFile.FullName))
    from x in Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        var a = audioItem;
        var flag = Filter.AudioItemMatchesFilter(ref a);
        return new { flag, audioItem = a };
    })
    where x.flag
    select x.audioItem;
    
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(audioItem =>
        {
            /* Your code to update the UI here */
        });
```

It was unclear to me whether it's creating a new `WAVEFile` or the call to `AudioItemMatchesFilter` that is taking the time so I wrapped both in `Observable.Start`. You also had a `ref` call and that makes the code a bit messy.

Nonetheless, this code handles all of the calls in the background and automatically moves the results as they come in to the dispatcher thread.